# Outputting from Logstash to Event Hubs is slow

Tags: java, logstash, jruby, azure-eventhub, telegraf

I am currently developing an Azure Event Hubs output plugin for Logstash and I have ran into a problem where after running for around 30 minutes logstash will get stuck for a bit because the output to event hubs is taking too long.

My technology stack:

Telegraf sending to logstash over tcp.

Logstash is using default pipeline settings.

Logstash is outputting to Event Hubs using the java createSync, sendSync methods.

How I create the connection:

```
connection_builder = EventHubs::ConnectionStringBuilder.new()
connection_builder.setNamespaceName(@service_namespace)
connection_builder.setEventHubName(@event_hub)
connection_builder.setSasKeyName(@sas_key_name)
connection_builder.setSasKey(@sas_key)

@executor_service = java::util::concurrent::Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
@eventhub_client = EventHubs::EventHubClient.createSync(connection_builder.toString(), @executor_service)
```

How I send the event:

```
event_data = EventHubs::EventData.create(body.to_java_bytes)
partition_key = get_partition_key(event)
        @eventhub_client.sendSync(event_data, partition_key)
```

Why is sending to Event Hubs so slow?

Do you think there would be any performance problems sending over AMQP?

If you need more context or code just ask and I will post below.

Comment: How many partitions did you provision for the event hub, how big are the messages and what is the rate?

Comment: 16 partition at 500-900 events every 15 seconds and each event is about 500 bytes

Comment: And how may throughput units did you provision? Got any server busy errors?

Comment: @PeterBons 3 TU, no server busy errors from what I could tell. But I am basically tripling the data my hubs process because I process everything with Stream Anaytics and send it to another hub on the same namespace. The tripling occurs because the SA breaks out compact events that it gets. So it about doubles the amount of events. Then sending that result to another EH makes the ending throughput tripple what it originally ingested. Though I don't think we are hitting the limit.

Comment: Did you take a look at [the monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-metrics-azure-monitor) already and did it show any unexpected metric values?

Comment: No unexpected values. It's strange because I decided to go and make a telegraf output plugin yesterday to see of it was a logstash/jruby problem and the telegraf output plugin works really well (it is in golang). Could the jvm or ruby java overhead be at fault?